# Atom IDE Python Modules not importing

Tags: python, atom-editor

Python modules not importing into Atom IDE. I am using:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Python 3.6

What I have done so far:

Loaded the environment Variables for my Python Directory. Which solved the issue of code running in
atom-runner.

Example Python urllib2 wasn't found I pip install urllib2 from Cmd it was succesful but didn't come up in atom when i ran the import command.

Anyhelp or suggestions if very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one python version installed in your system ?

Comment: I just have python3.6 was considering completely removing it and get getting 3.5 or 2.7 just to see if i get better results. I thought urlllib2 was apart of the standard library and it apparently it isn't.

Comment: The urllibs got reworked with the release of python3. You can see [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html) that there’s only urllib in python3. If you need to use urllib, you should be using the ``urllib`` module in python3.

Comment: Ok thank you. I figured that out my problem is anything I add to libs\site-packages using pip won't come up when I run it in idle or atom. When I import it I get module not found. This is the same for even the module requests.

Comment: Im facing the exact same problem.. where else do i add a new python package if not in lib\site-packgaes?